# Playing a sound in iOS pauses background music

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

How do I play a sound in iOS without pausing the background music?

I have this:

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alert" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:soundPath];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url error:nil];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
[audioPlayer play];
```

And yet any background music is stopped. What am I missing?

I also tried this, to no avail:

```
- (void)alarm:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
    [self setupAudioSession];
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alert" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:soundPath];

    AVPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL: url];
    [audioPlayer play];
}

- (void)setupAudioSession {
    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    OSStatus activationResult = 0;
    activationResult          = AudioSessionSetActive(true);

    UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;

    AudioSessionSetProperty
    (
     kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
     sizeof(sessionCategory),
     &sessionCategory
     );

    OSStatus propertySetError = 0;
    UInt32 allowMixing        = true;

    propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty
    (
     kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
     sizeof(allowMixing),
     &allowMixing
     );
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate audio session, something like this:

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

OSStatus activationResult = 0;
activationResult          = AudioSessionSetActive(true);

UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;

AudioSessionSetProperty
(
    kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
    sizeof(sessionCategory),
    &sessionCategory
 );

OSStatus propertySetError = 0;
UInt32 allowMixing        = true;

propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty
(
    kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
    sizeof(allowMixing),
    &allowMixing
);
```

Comment: strange, it seems to work fine for me when using `AVPlayer`. Is `AVPlayer` an option for you? Possibly you could try that, at least to see if the code is working (which it should).

Comment: I updated my example with what I tried, and background sound is being stopped.

Comment: take the last line out `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];`

Comment: Still stops music. Is the fact that it's a wav an issue?

Comment: It shouldn't be, I'm also playing a wav file and your code seems fine. Very strange. Is this the only place in your project that you try to start any type of audio session?

Comment: My original code actually works. I forgot how I setup my build process for a bit, and I wasn't hitting the right cordova.exec callbacks. Woops!